# will before synchronized statement before another synchronized nock?

Tags: java, multithreading

If there are two global no volatile `int` variables a , b and `object` obj ; threads 1 has :

```
 1 ++a;
 2 synchronized(obj){
 3   ++b; 
 4 }
 5 print a
```

Thead 2 has :

```
 1 synchronized(obj){
 2   ++b; 
 3 }
 4 print a
```

So my questions are :

1、 can the 1 line code reorder after the 4 line code in thread 1?

2、 If thread 1 first lock unlock obj , then thread 2 do ; so will the thread 2 get the `a` correctly when `print a` .

Comment: If neither of these fields are `volatile`, all bets are off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements before, during or after a synchronized block cannot be re-ordered across those boundaries. They can be reordered with statements are also the same side of these boundaries.

> If neither of these fields are volatile, all bets are off.

This is true without synchronized, however, synchronized also introduces full memory barriers.

> can the 1 line code reorder after the 4 line code in thread 1?

It cannot be ordered to after line 2.

> If thread 1 first lock unlock obj , then thread 2 do ; so will the thread 2 get the a value correctly when print a .

Provided thread 1 enters `synchronized` before thread 2, yes.  However, thread 2 might execute first in which case it could see an old value.

Answer (score 2):

The following rules defined in the Java Language Specification applies to your code:

> [**17.4.4. Synchronization Order**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4)
>
> Synchronization actions induce the *synchronized-with* relation on actions, defined as follows:
>
> 1. An **unlock** action on monitor `m` *synchronizes-with* all subsequent **lock** actions on `m` (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

<-- -->

> [**17.4.5. Happens-before Order**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)
>
> Two actions can be ordered by a *happens-before* relationship. If one action *happens-before* another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.
>
> If we have two actions `x` and `y`, we write `hb(x, y)` to indicate that `x` *happens-before* `y`.
>
> 2. If `x` and `y` are actions of the same thread and `x` comes before `y` in program order, then `hb(x, y)`.
> 3. If an action `x` *synchronizes-with* a following action `y`, then we also have `hb(x, y)`.
> 4. If `hb(x, y)` and `hb(y, z)`, then `hb(x, z)`.

Now lets apply that to your code:

```java
A1 ++a;
A2 synchronized(obj){
A3   ++b; 
A4 }
A5 print a
```

```java
B1 synchronized(obj){
B2   ++b; 
B3 }
B4 print a
```

Rule 2 states:

```
A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> A4 -> A5
B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> B4
```

---

The result depends on which thread arrives at the `synchronized` block first. The problem occurs if thread B arrives first, where rules 1 + 3 states:

```
B3 -> A2
```

Combined:

```
A1 →→→→→→→→→→→→→ A2 → A3 → A4 → A5
              ↑
B1 → B2 → B3 →→→ B4
```

There is no *happens-before* relation between A1 (`++a`) and B4 (`print a`), so results are unpredictable.

---

If thread A arrives first, rules 1 + 3 states:

```
B4 -> B1
```

Combined

```
A1 → A2 → A3 → A4 →→→ A5
                   ↓
                   →→ B1 → B2 → B3 → B4
```

Rule 4 then states that `hb(A1, A5)` and `hb(A1, B4)` which means that `++a` is guaranteed to *happen before* both `print a` statements.

---

To answer your specific questions:

> can the 1 line code reorder after the 4 line code in thread 1?

In thread 1? No.
As seen from thread 2? Yes, see above.

> If thread 1 first lock unlock obj , then thread 2 do ; so will the thread 2 get the a correctly when print a .

Yes, if thread 1 locks first, thread 2 will print updated value of `a`, see above.